# Text running into itself

Tags: javascript, html, webfonts

I have a website which I am building; I have a problem in that sometimes I load the page and the text runs into itself. Sometimes just hovering over the text will cause the problem to go away, sometimes I have to reload the page. I use webfonts (Google fonts) and wondered if it was anything to do with that.

Here is a screenshot of the problem:

[image: Screenshot]

If anyone knows what is happening here and how to fix it, I'd appreciate it.

**Edit**

Here is my code, as requested. I can't get the problem to exhibit itself on there though; even on my dev site it is not consistent.

```js
WebFont.load({
  google: {
    families: ['Ubuntu:300,400,700,400italic,700italic:latin']
  }
});
```

```css
div#wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
  margin: 0 auto 3em;
}
#wrapper,
header div,
footer div {
  max-width: 900px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 90%;
}
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Ubuntu', serif;
}
.ajaxcol {
  display: table-row;
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  font-weight: 300;
}
.post,
.page {
  clear: both;
  margin-bottom: 3em;
}
.page {
  margin: 1em 0 0 0;
}
#maincol p,
#sidebar p,
#pagecol p,
td,
li {
  line-height: 1.8em;
}
#wrapper h2,
#wrapper h3,
#wrapper h4,
#wrapper p {
  color: #2E2E2E;
}
p {
  margin: 0.3em 3px 1em 3px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="wrapper" style="padding-top: 1em; opacity: 1;">
    <div id="pagecol" class="ajaxcol">
      <div class="page">
        <header>
          <h2>Header</h2>
        </header>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque dapibus tellus odio, gravida posuere nibh aliquam sed. Sed vulputate maximus nibh malesuada tincidunt. Sed convallis faucibus nisi, imperdiet vehicula arcu sollicitudin finibus.
          Maecenas aliquam neque eros, nec facilisis purus ultricies ac. Praesent feugiat lorem a ipsum interdum ornare. Etiam elit metus, laoreet vel consequat ut, mattis vel mauris. Donec ut libero diam.</p>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Can you please at least show the relevant html and css? it may also be a problem related to either css or just html rendering.

Comment: Question has been edited

Comment: do you still get this issue if you load google webfonts with an `@import`? i suspect this issue is due to the font not being fully loaded at render

Comment: Is the problem related to any specific web browser?

Comment: Tried in different browsers, three different PCs with three different OS and didn't encounter the problem. Did you try to @import the font? Also, another question: can you reproduce the problem on other machines too? did you try to entirely close your browser or reboot your machine? Sometimes such problems can be related to memory leaks or something like that, or they may be related to an invalid HTML markup, but it doesn't really seems to be the case.

Comment: I see the fiddle to be perfect in FireFox Windows

Comment: Please don't post links to code on their own. If JSFiddle went pop, your question becomes useless to anyone reading it. I have edited your question for you and added your code in.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
#wrapper, header div, footer div {
  max-width: 900px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
}
```

instead of:

```
#wrapper, header div, footer div {
  max-width: 900px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 90%;
}
```

`width` changed to `100%`.